# Laravel 5.2 shows "The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given" when I try to use DB::statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to use DB::statement() method to run a SQL, but I can't get it to work and it shows "UnexpectedValueException in Response.php line 395:
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given."

Here's the code:

```
$students = DB::statement('select stu_agency,avg(stu_rank1) as avggrade from students group by stu_agency');
return $students;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database):

> Some database statements should not return any value. For these types of operations, you may use the statement method on the DB facade.

You are searching for

```
$students = DB::table('students')
                  ->select('stu_agency', DB::raw('avg(stu_rank1) as avggrade'))
                  ->groupBy('stu_agency')
                  ->get();
return $students;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DB::statement()` method is used to execute SQL statements that don't return a value. The method itself will return `true`/`false`.

If you want to run a select statement, you want `DB::select()`.

You can read up on the [Laravel Database documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database)